# Log Determinant in Theano Loss Function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, theano, deep-learning

I'm using Theano (python package for deep learning), but I'm very new to it and I'm running into an issue with a term in my loss function. The term involves taking the logarithm of the determinant of a matrix; the matrix is a function of a layer of hidden units in my network.
I import Tensor, and Tensor.nlinalg:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import theano.tensor.nlinalg as Tnlinalg
```

and then stick this term in my loss function:

```
my_mat_det = Tnlinalg.Det(computed_matrix)
log_det_term = -T.log(my_mat_det)
```

but when I attempt to train it I get the following exception and traceback:

```
File "/SdaModule.py", line 88, in __init__
  log_det_term = -T.log(my_mat_det)
File "/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 481, in __call__
  node = self.make_node(*inputs, **kwargs)
File "/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/elemwise.py", line 527, in make_node
  inputs = map(as_tensor_variable, inputs)
File "/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/basic.py", line 202, in as_tensor_variable
  raise AsTensorError("Cannot convert %s to TensorType" % str_x, type(x))
theano.tensor.var.AsTensorError: ('Cannot convert Det to TensorType', <class 'theano.tensor.nlinalg.Det'>)
```

Can anyone offer any advice?
Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`theano.tensor.nlinalg.Det` in the [linear algebra package](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nlinalg.html) is an operation class, not an operation function. You need to first init an instance of the class and then apply it to the node representing your matrix. For example,

```
import numpy

import theano
import theano.tensor.nlinalg

x = theano.tensor.matrix('x', dtype=theano.config.floatX)
p = theano.shared(numpy.array([[2, 0], [0, 3]], dtype=theano.config.floatX))
y = theano.dot(x, p)
c = theano.tensor.log(theano.tensor.nlinalg.Det()(y))
g = theano.grad(c, x)

print theano.printing.pp(g)
```

Note the difference between `theano.tensor.nlinalg.Det()(y)` and `theano.tensor.nlinalg.Det(y)`.